# Reading double quoted string values from text in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a text file with the value formatted as follows, please note there there is no separator between values.

```
"col1""col2""col3""col4"
"val1""date1""number1""val1"
"val2""date2""number2""val2"
"val3""date3""number3""val3"
"val4""date4""number4""val4"
```

How do I read this file as csv in pandas ?

Comment: Must it go directly into pandas? For instance if it is a one-time thing, you could open it in any text editor and do a find-and-replace, changing each "" to ","

Comment: Yes, this is actually a big dataset text file, need to process every month automatically. This is supposed to be a Tab delimited file, but original developer made mistake and no tabs in between , but this was working fine as SAS was treating double quotes as separator, but now this need to be handled by python.

Comment: Is performance and speed a big deal? Else following my comment above, you can have a first function that creates a temp file with commas included, then passes it to pandas?

Comment: By the way `df = pd.read_csv("bad.csv", sep='""')` works - it just gives dangling " at the start of the first field and end of the last field.

Comment: Thank you very much, @VBB.  I just need to process first and last cols with that dangling " then. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using the `python` engine for [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) and specifying a regex of `"+` (i.e. one or more quotes) as the separator. This yields a DataFrame with empty first and last columns, which can be removed with [`pd.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html?highlight=iloc):

```py
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep='"+', engine='python').iloc[:, 1:-1]
df
```

Output:

```
   col1   col2     col3  col4
0  val1  date1  number1  val1
1  val2  date2  number2  val2
2  val3  date3  number3  val3
3  val4  date4  number4  val4
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working solution - not the most elegant, but does the job:

```
mylist = []
with open("filename.csv", 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile.readlines():
        mylist.append(line[1:-2].split('""'))
data = pd.Dataframe(mylist)
```